# Stop Visual Studio asking for each project: has been modified outside the environment. Do you wish to reload?

Tags: visual-studio

Do you wish to reload the project? Where's the Reload All option.
Vote for this question and hopefully MS will implement a fix in VS2020.

With pleany of projects in a solution I for one dread doing an svn update.

This has been an issue from VS2003 but after a decade of clicking mindlessly on buttons it's getting on my wick.

Does anyone have a hack / registry entry / secret way of saying yes short of saying ignore (quick), closing and reloading the solution?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can tweak for this scenario.  Both are under the Documents Options

- Tools -> Options
- Environment -> Documents

The first option is to just uncheck "Detect when files changed outside the environment".  This will stop the reload dialog but will force you to manually reload.

The second option just below it is a bit better "Auto-load changes, if saved".  This will just automatically load the changes without prompting you for every project.

Personally though I would go a slightly different route here.  The problem is occuring because your managing your source code control outside of Visual Studio.  If you switched to using an addin to manage within Visual Studio it would remove these problems altogether.  For svn there are several free packages available including [Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) which is fairly popular

Comment: I do use Anksvn but also Tortoise. Will try and do more updates from within VS - good point!

Comment: Thanks. I was getting the annoying popup every time I switched between classes!

Comment: The behavior I want is I think the same as in Squirrel's original post, namely to detect all the project changes, and then to reload them wholesale, rather than prompting me project-by-project. Is anyone actually getting this by checking both "Detect when files changed...." and "Auto-load changes, if saved"? I just tried this change in VS2005, and it doesn't seem to have the desired effect. This *does* seem to auto-load individual changed source files (e.g. foo.cs), but it's still asking me about projects one by one.

Comment: I have this same issue with my workflows (xaml) and I am using TFS. It prompts me several times every time I save. Sometimes when I say yes by accident it crashes Visual Studio 2010. Other times just a huge stacktrace in a messagebox. Any idea why this happening when I am using TFS?

Comment: I get this with TFS service (free hosted version) really strange because it is integrated with VS

Comment: `Auto-load changes, if saved` was unchecked and checking it fixed it for me. I don't know how it became unchecked but it created some quite annoying behavior for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165643(VS.80).aspx

DetectFileChangesOutsideIDE

Get/Set (Boolean)

Determines whether the environment automatically reloads files opened in the IDE when the operating system notifies the IDE that the files have been modified on disk.

EDIT:
Some clarification, as that page isn't immediately obvious.

Tools Menu->Options -> Environment->Documents->Uncheck Detect when file is changed outside the Environment

Comment: Doesn't this just *not* reload documents, as opposed to reloading all?